# In Qt how can I know which modifier keys are pressed without overriding the key press and release event functions

Tags: qt5, keypress

I am writing a UI manager where, when you ctrl-alt-rclick a widget, it allows you to edit the widget.

I have implemented key press and release functions in the top level window so as to be able to detect the state of the ctrl and alt keys. However it is very flaky as if another window or dialog gets the focus, the key press events go there instead of to my event listeners.

Every other GUI toolkit I have ever met, and every single Window manager system I have ever met, allow you to check the state of keys at any time, rather than rely on listening to key press/release events.

I have searched the Qt documentation in depth, but cannot find any functionality that would allow me to simply check if a specific key is being held down at any time.

In Qt, how can I detect the state of keyboard keys without monitoring events?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to monitor the keyboard constantly.  If you want to begin some action on ctrl-alt-right-click then you can check the modifier keys when you receive the [mouse click](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmouseevent.html) event, right?

Comment: @G.M. I need to monitor it constantly because I cannot find any way to check the "modifier keys". I would love to do that - how? Also, thanks for all your responses to all my questions over the last week or so.

Comment: @G.M. Got it, thanks - it is a property on the base QInput class which is why I didn't see it before :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `[static] Qt::KeyboardModifiers QGuiApplication::queryKeyboardModifiers()` ?

Comment: Perfect except that I need to make sure that the QApplication instance I have is a QGuiApplication instance.

Comment: Now that you mention it: funny that it is part of QGuiApplication. One would assume that console applications would also like to query keyboard states.

Comment: *except that I need to make sure that the QApplication instance I have is a QGuiApplication instance* It will never be anything else in a GUI application :) So that's a non-concern.